# I.E. 11 breaks flex in html5/bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Im currently working on my first website and trying to get a few things done in regards to layout. Ive been using the latest version of Bootstrap and been relatively successful so far. I am running into issues however when adjusting the view of some of the columns in my tables.

As I am trying to keep them all the same height for aesthetics, I have used flex columns to get done what I wanted.

With designing flex columns when creating a table, the information does not render successfully in I.E. 11 or below, as seen here: [I.E Flex Rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IHnu.jpg).

My current CSS is based off [Equal height columns with CSS Flexbox](http://www.bootply.com/126437#). I am aware of the but am having difficulty with the interaction between the code from Bootstrap and the CSS Flexbox when using it in conjunction with panels.

The flexed columns successfully renders with the mentioned code in Edge (25.10586.0.0), Chrome (50.0.2661.102), and Firefox (46.0.1).

Comment: See *Known Issues* tab here: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Answer (score 0):

IE11 has partial support for flexbox. please see http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Thank you! That lets me know at least to not fight with it any longer.